# Select characters separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I need to select only day, month and year (separately) and then calculate days until due. Why is this not functioning correctly? Am I using the `substr` correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/XeqPT/15/

```
function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
  var now = new Date(),
      dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
      days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days

  return Math.round(days);
}

$('#paging1 ul li').each(function () {

    var monthDue = $(this).find('.due-date').text().substr(0,2);
    var dayDue = $(this).find('.due-date').text().substr(3,2);
    var yearDue = $(this).find('.due-date').text().substr(6,4);

    $(this).find('.days-due').text(daysUntil(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue));

});
```

Comment: What's for the tag math??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var monthDue = $('.due-date').text().substr(0,2);
var dayDue = $('.due-date').text().substr(3,2);
var yearDue = $('.due-date').text().substr(6,4);
```

I will also suggest you to look at moment.js for date manipulation or calculation. 
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` wasn't what you thought it was and [wasn't finding the `.due-date` element](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XeqPT/11/), try this approach:

```
/* caching the relevant text to avoid having to find the same element/text
   multiple times: */
var due = $('.due-date').text(),
    monthDue = due.substr(0,2),
    dayDue = due.substr(3,2),
    yearDue = due.substr(6,4);

// to demonstrate that you're getting the relevant text
console.log(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue);

$('.days-due').each(function(){
    $(this).text(daysUntil(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XeqPT/9/).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XeqPT/21/)**</kbd>

```
function daysUntil(untilDate) {
    var Time = new Date(untilDate).getTime();
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var difference = Time-currTime; 
    return Math.ceil( difference/(1000*60*60*24) );   
}


$('.days-due').each(function() {
    var dateUntil = $('.due-date').text(); // use something more specific
    $(this).text( daysUntil( dateUntil ) );
} );
```